# SQL Server PRINT statement in stored procedure is being concatenated with RAISERROR message by System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, raiserror, system.data.sqlclient

My fairly simple stored procedure does this on line 44:

```
IF @a = @b
    RAISERROR('blah blah blah', 11, 1)
    RETURN
```

The stored procedure is invoked client-side using the .NET Framework `System.Data.SqlClient` library:

```
   try
   {
        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand();
        c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        c.CommandText = "procname";
        c.ExecuteNonQuery()   // execute the stored procedure 
   }
   catch(SqlException sex)
       throw sex;
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
        throw ex;
   }
```

When `ex` is caught, its value is `blah blah blah` + CRLF + `1259`

Where is that `1259` coming from? Does it correspond to severity 11?

Comment: FYI, you should really be using `THROW`, not `RAISERROR`.

Comment: @Larnu: Legacy SP, it predated THROW.

Comment: @Larnu. I'm not using an unsupported version of SQL Server. I'm using SQL Server 2017 but many of the application's SPs date back quite a few years.

Comment: Catch `SqlException` instead. It has an `Errors` property with finer-grained details.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Just found it.  There's a `PRINT` statement some lines above the RAISERROR.  Didn't know that (unrelated) PRINT statements get appended to the error message!

```
  PRINT 'Fee fie fo fum'

  <snip>

  if @a = @b
     RAISERROR('blah blah blah', 11, 1)
     return
```

Client-side the SqlException Message property is "blah blah blah" + CRLF + "Fee fie fo fum"

Comment: *" Didn't know that (unrelated) PRINT statements get appended to the error message!"* They don't.

Comment: They do. I changed it to "PRINT 'Fee fie fo fum' " and now my error message client-side reads `blah blah blah` + CRLF +  `fee fie fo fum`.   Must be a`System.Data.SqlClient` feature.

Comment: Same behavior with `SqlException`.

Comment: The database engine returns all messages generated by `PRINT`, `RAISERROR`, `THROW` along with informational, warning, error, and API messages back to the client. The differentiator is that errors with severity 11 or greater (`SqlError.Class` >= 11) will also throw an exception with SqlClient and most other APIs. The `SqlException.Errors` collection will contain all the messages, though, so you'll need to filter on `Class` to discard the informational and warning messages.

Comment: Thank you @Dan Guzman. I had never encountered this behavior with PRINT and RAISERROR and System.Data.SqlClient before.